# How can I easily enable PDB output for all projects and configurations in a large solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, configuration, projects-and-solutions, pdb-files

I have a big solution with over 40 projects and 8 configurations (debug, release etc.). Is there an easy way to enable full PDB output in **all** projects for **all** configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by editing all the .csproj files directly. Use a text based find and replace tool to find all `<DebugType>` tags and insert the desired value.

Example: `<DebugType>none</DebugType>` becomes `<DebugType>full</DebugType>`.